# Right aligning div inline with a left aligned div?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am experiencing difficulties when I am trying to Right align text links inside a div.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. But this is the code for the div that is supposed be right aligned:

```
 <div class="menu">
     <a href="http://google.com" class="button">Home</a>
     <a href="http://google.com" class="button">Sign In</a>
     <a href="http://google.com" class="button">Join The Crowd!</a>
 </div>
```

And all the code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GSfmf/1

I am wanting the buttons still vertically-centered in the header_div, but aligned to the right. And anything that I do doesn't move it.

Thanks, sorry for being foolish about the css.

Comment: I'm really confused as to what you want aligned where.

Comment: Apply `width: 100%` to your `div.header_div { }`

Answer (score 1):

Take out display table from your header div.  Is there a reason your displaying it as a table?

[Works fine when you take out display header](http://jsfiddle.net/GSfmf/3/)

```
div.header_div{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px 50px 15px 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the css stylesheet just add the following code...think it wd work
.menu{ float:right;}